# No me funcionan los CSS en IE10 y IE11

Tags: html5, css3, internet-explorer

Estoy intentando crear unos CSS para que me funcione correctamente la web en IE 9 o superior, pero cuando los inserto, sólo me lo reconoce en IE9 pero en IE10 o IE11 no.

He puesto eh el head

```
<!--[if IE]><link href="css/airN/airN-ie.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"><![endif]-->
```

Y solo me lo reconoce en el IE9, he intentado poner:

```
<!--[if IE 10]><link href="css/airN/airN-ie.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"><![endif]-->
```

Y lo mismo para el IE11 para ver si poniéndolo así me reconocía los CSS para estas versiones de IE pero no me reconoce los CSS

¿Cómo podría hacer para que me reconozcan los CSS para IE9 y superior?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que los comentarios condicionales no son soportados por los navegadores IE10 o superior: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/compatibility/hh801214(v=vs.85) Prueba con el condicional opuesto, es decir: <!--[if !IE]> y dentro coloca todos los CSS que NO son para IE, fuera del comentario coloca los CSS que SI son para IE 9 y superior.

Comment: al ponerlo al reves `<!--[if !IE]><link href="css/airN/airN.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"><![endif]-->` y fuera `<link href="css/airN/airN-ie.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">` en IE se ve bien, pero en el resto de navegadores pilla como principales los css de IE y no los que no son de IE

Comment: en los CSS para el resto de navegadores tengo que poner el **!important**  en los css que he modificado en IE?

Comment: Usar el condicional de negación tampoco te va a servir de nada, como han comentado a partir de IE10 no se soportan y el resto de navegadores tampoco los soporta así que ninguno va a leer los estilos del comentario. Tendrás que usar alguna otra técnica, te pongo una aunque hay otras: http://browserbu.gs/css-hacks/media-min-width-0-backslash-0/